# Motivic cohomology of a point

Tags: algebraic-k-theory, motives, motivic-cohomology, algebraic-cycles, chow-groups

I was wondering how much is known about the integral motivic cohomology groups of $\mathrm{Spec}\, k$, $H^{n,p}_{\mathrm{mot}}(\mathrm{Spec}\, k,\mathbb{Z})$. One knows that $H^{n,n}_{\mathrm{mot}}(\mathrm{Spec}\, k,\mathbb{Z})\simeq K^M_n(k)$, the Milnor $K$-theory of the field $k$. Also, because of the isomorphism to higher Chow groups $H^{n,p}_{\mathrm{mot}}(X,\mathbb{Z})\simeq CH^p(X,2p-n)$ when $k$ is perfect, we get $H^{2p,p}_{\mathrm{mot}}(\mathrm{Spec}\, k,\mathbb{Z})\simeq CH^p(\mathrm{Spec}\, k)=0$ if $p\neq 0$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ otherwise. This also implies $H^{n,p}_{\mathrm{mot}}(\mathrm{Spec}\, k,\mathbb{Z})$ vanishes for $n>p$.

> For which $(n,p)$ is $H^{n,p}_{\mathrm{mot}}(\mathrm{Spec}\, k,\mathbb{Z})$ known to vanish? In other words, is there any $n\neq p$ for which the group is non-trivial?

Comment: Not much is known, the vanishing result mentioned in the question is essentially all (unless you ask for specific fields). For finite fields, a lot more groups are known to vanish. By Borel's computations we know that $H^1(\operatorname{Spec} k,\mathbb{Z}(n))$ is nontrivial for number fields with a complex place.

Comment: If the higher Chow groups were to vanish for all $n\neq p$, then the spectral sequence from motivic cohomology to $K$-theory would degenerate immediately, in which case Quillen $K$-theory and Milnor $K$-theory would be identical, which they are frequently not (for example for finite fields).  So whenever $K^M\neq K^Q$,  there must be other non-vanishing motivic cohomology groups.

Comment: We have $H^{n-d,n}(Spec(k), \mathbb{Z}/p) = K_{n-d}^M(k)/p$ for $d \ge 0$, which also implies (via the Bockstein sequence) that there must be many non-vanishing integral groups.